# How to move a VB .NET website project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

How to move a VB .NET website project to another computer?

Is there a way to run the project in another computer without visual studio installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Website in Visual Studio is always calling IISExpress, which is simulating local server. If you want to only run it in another pc, there should be OS Windows Server with IIS. On the other hand it will not be able to start alone.

OR you can install IIS Express and set config to enable your website in another pc

- Download IIS Express in that pc from MS site.
- Than in config file of IISExpress, set binding URL port as random 4 digit (in my case it is *1000*) number. (c:\Users\YOUR_USER\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config)
- in cmd set
  `netsh http add urlacl url=http://{PC IP}:10000/ user=everyone`
- in config file find section of your project. It looks like: 
  `<site name="NameOfMyApp" id="34">`
- and add there:
  `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:10000:{PC IP}" />`